# Expanded Row is not Collapse in React and AntDesgin

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design table in which I am using row expanded functionality. my query is when I click any row of the table the row is opening but not collapse back. i just want it in that way if i click on '+' icon the row should be open and if click '_' icon row should collapse and also if the previous row is open on click of next row the previous row should collapse also.... please give any solution i am giving the link in which i have half of code is implemented.. help will be appreciated.... Thank in advance.

```
enter code here
```

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-http-jxf1m?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if prev and next are same it means collapse.
Else it is expand.

[Working link](https://codesandbox.io/s/prakash-ant-table-expand-collapse-ivf4f)

```js
const onExpand = (_, key) => {

  setExpandedKey((prev) => {
    const newKey = key.key;
    if (prev !== newKey) {
      return newKey;
    }
    return null;
  });
};
```